# Generate a view to identify first entry and last entry of a particular value in a column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The sheet is 150 000 entries long and there are five columns. In a particular column, there are many repeated entries. The column name is "CNumber'. And the entries are like:

```
123
334
233
123
224
```

.. so on. I want to generate a view so that for a particular CNumber say 123, I want to identify the first entry and its last entry.

***Meaning:*** There is a column which says "Time". So in a particular day, say CNumber "123" was used for 12 times and hence it is input 12 times in the sheet. But I just want to identify the first and the last time it was used so that I can calculate the time it was there in the company premises on a particular day.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas solution:

```
#create DataFrame from file
df = pd.read_csv(file)

print(df)
   CNumber  Time
0      123     1
1      334     2
2      123     3
3      123     4
4      224     5
```

Filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
a = 123
df1 = df[df['CNumber'] == a]
print (df1)
   CNumber  Time
0      123     1
2      123     3
3      123     4
```

Get the first and last value of the filtered column `Time` by indexing the positions using  [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
first = df1['Time'].iloc[0]
last = df1['Time'].iloc[-1]

print ('For value {} is first time: {} and last time: {}'.format(a, first, last))
For value 123 is first time: 1 and last time: 4
```

If need generate Dataframe for all first and last values (if unique values like `224` columns values are same):

```
df2 = df.groupby('CNumber')['Time'].agg(['first','last'])
print (df2)

         first  last
CNumber             
123          1     4
224          5     5
334          2     2
```

But is possible filter only duplicated values:

```
df3=df[df['CNumber'].duplicated(keep=False)].groupby('CNumber')['Time'].agg(['first','last'])
print (df3)
         first  last
CNumber             
123          1     4
```

Comment: Does the job. Thanks!
If I want a generated view, like if I enter "123" or any other CNum and I want its first entry and last entry to be displayed, will I have to use a loop? If so or if not, then how to proceed in either case?

Comment: @user68263, no, loop dont use in pandas, because slow. Give me  a sec.

Comment: @user68263 - I add some solutions, I hope it is what need.

Comment: Superr. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a double meaning of "first" and "last" when considering time. It can either mean "last in the dataset" or "last in time".

The following code uses group by to handle all `CNumber`s at once and shows the difference between the two interpretations.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["CNumber", "Time"]
                  , data=[
                      [123, 4],
                      [321, 3],
                      [123, 1],
                      [789, 5],
                      [123, 6],
                      [123, 2],
                      [321, 0]
                  ])
print(df, end='\n\n')

groups = df.groupby(['CNumber'])

print("Maximal time")
print(groups.max(), end='\n\n')


print("Last occurrence")
for group in groups:
    print('For CNumber {}, last occurence is {}'
    .format(group[0], group[1]['Time'].iloc[-1]))
```

This yields the following output:

```
       CNumber  Time
0      123     4
1      321     3
2      123     1
3      789     5
4      123     6
5      123     2
6      321     0

Maximal time
         Time
CNumber      
123         6
321         3
789         5

Last occurrence
For CNumber 123, last occurence is 2
For CNumber 321, last occurence is 0
For CNumber 789, last occurence is 5
```